# How can I have floating divs to left and right?

Tags: css, html

I need to show a page with a product icon (which is usually 300x400px in dimensions) on the left side of the page and its details on right side.

I thought I'd put the description in rows of a table.I created 3 div elements- a containerdiv,an icondiv,and a detailsdiv and tried to float the icondiv to left and detailsdiv to right.I got the icondiv on left side of page,but the detailsdiv is shown below the icondiv not side by side!

Ideally the icondiv should be 25-30% in width of containerdiv and detailsdiv should take up the rest of the width.I am wondering if there is a way to do it without mentioning width in pixels.

please correct me if there is something wrong with my css

thanks

mark

```
<div class ="itemdetailscontainer">
    <div class="itemicondiv">
        <img border="0" src="${item.isbn }.png"  alt="${item.isbn }.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="itemdetailsdiv">
        <table id="itemdetailstable" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>

            ${item.name }

            </td>
         </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>by</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>${item.maker.name }</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <p>Description:</p>
              <p>${item.description}</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

css is

```
div.itemdetailscontainer{
    float:clear;
}
div.itemicondiv{
    float:left; 
}
div.itemdetailsdiv{
    float:right;    
}
```

---

I tried this

```
div.itemdetailscontainer{
    width:100%; 
}
div.itemicondiv{
    float:left;
    width:25%;  
}
div.itemdetailsdiv{
    float:right;
    width:75%;  
}
```

and this gets the effect..

thanks everyone for responding..Is the use of 
width : 25% etc problematic? Do I need to hardcode width  in pixels etc?
The overflow property was new for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/Uys4s/

```
div.itemdetailscontainer{
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #eee
}
div.itemicondiv{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    background: #ccc
}
div.itemdetailsdiv{
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #aaa
}
```

- `width: 30%` handles this: "Ideally the icondiv should be 25-30% in width of containerdiv"
- `overflow: hidden` on `div.itemdetailsdiv` handles this: "detailsdiv should take up the rest of the width".
- `overflow: hidden` on `div.itemdetailscontainer` will contain the floats in the way I think you imagine the nonexistent `clear: float` will. Take a look at the [valid values of `clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/clear). If you desperately wanted to use `clear: both` to clear your floats, this is how you'd do it: http://jsfiddle.net/Uys4s/1/ - but `overflow: hidden` is easier.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that your container (itemdetailscontainer) has enough width to hold them side by side. Inspect with Firebug or other tool and check the width.

Also I would suggest you use div's for the itemdetailstable for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing called float:clear It should be :

```
float : none;
```

or if you're trying to clear the float it should be :

```
clear:both
```

Answer (score 0):

`float: clear` does not exist!
I think you want this: `clear: left/right/both`